# Unable to connect to GCE instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

I started several GCE instances and was unable to connect to even 1 of them using ssh. For debian wheezy instances the ssh server appeared to be not running ("nc IP 22" times out). Even though I enabled ICMP in default network, debian instances did not respond to ping.

CentOS instances responds to ping and I was able to get an ssh banner using nc intermittently. But connecting using ssh command repeatedly timed out.

I suspected a network outage but "gcutil listzones" showed that all the zones I was using, were UP (us-cental)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gce-operations/coBWszq91j4/dRPq5_gJ3t4J:

> We're investigating an issue with network connectivity to new Google Compute Engine instances. Currently-running instances are not affected.  We will provide more information shortly.